# Prevent form resubmit on refresh in struts2 (with action messages and fields messages preservation)

Tags: forms, struts2, refresh, form-submit

I got a simple form validation and submission that works great

Here is my struts.xml :

```
    <action name="register" class="registerAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultWithoutAuthenticationStack"/>
        <result type="tiles" name="input">
            <param name="titleKey">global.title.register</param>
            <param name="location">register</param>
        </result>
        <result type="tiles" name="success">register.success</result>
    </action>
```

My jsp form :

```
<s:form method="post" action="register.action" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="usernameRegister" id="usernameRegister" key="global.username" labelposition="left" />
    <s:password name="passwordRegister" id="passwordRegister" key="global.password" labelposition="left" />
    <s:password name="passwordConfirmRegister" id="passwordConfirmRegister" key="global.password.confirm" labelposition="left" />
    <s:textfield name="emailRegister" id="emailRegister" key="global.email" labelposition="left" />
    <s:submit key="global.register" name="submitRegister" method="goRegister"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

And my submit function :

```
public String goRegister(){
    user.setUsername(getUsernameRegister());
    user.setPassword(getPasswordRegister());
    user.setEmail(getEmailRegister());
    userService.addUser(user);

    ArrayList<String> successMessageUsername = new ArrayList<String>();

    successMessageUsername.add(getUsernameRegister());
    this.addActionSuccess(getText("global.register.success", successMessageUsername));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Nothing fancy !

The problem is I got a windows asking for resubmit form informations when I refresh my page on success page or form page (when validation failed)

How can I prevent that ?

Thx

EDIT : I add the action messages and fields messages preservation to my question
How to preserve the actions messages and fields messages (validation) with a redirection ?

Comment: I can't aswer myself now but I'll post asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

On success, redirect to the "you've registered" page. That way if the user refreshes, they just get that same page again.

Comment: Thx I'll try this :) Can I use this for the failed validation form too ? I mean redirect to the form with the fields values / error ? How do you set this on the struts.xml

Comment: Since I didn't ask for messages preservation in first place, I accept your answer (it was a good place to begin searching), if you are interested with messages, field messages preservation, look at below :)

Comment: @Fluckysan If the registration fails, I don't see why you'd bother redirecting; show the input page again. If you want to preserve action state, use the scope interceptor, or just save the messages in session and remove them yourself.

Comment: I want to redirect to prevent the refresh browser popup "Do you want to resubmit values" after validation failed, I'm able to do so with my own MessageStoreInterceptor (didn't know It existed so I developed mine >_<) but my forms values are wiped. Does it exist a method to achieve the 2 (no more refresh popup and store validation error) ?

Comment: @Fluckysan Yes, the [scope](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html) or [store](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html) interceptors. Personally, I think they're both a little bulky and usually use a small flash-style interceptor, but the functionality is the same.

Comment: I'll look this 2 interceptors, as I understand for now : store interceptor only store messages and scope store values, so I have to use both (scope for repopulate field value and store for actions messages and field action messages)

Comment: @Fluckysan Where do you think the messages/etc. are? They're action properties.

Comment: Yep they are, I just have to find them(form values) and develop a generic interceptor :) Can you post your interceptor please? Thx for your answers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5769/discussion-between-fluckysan-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 0):

Oki after Dave Newton's suggestion I dig up a little to complete the correct way to do so :)

Here is my answer so far, no more refresh, backward or forward resubmission of your form and preserve the ValidationAware messages (errors and messages)

My struts.xml :

```
    <action name="register" class="registerAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultWithoutAuthenticationStack"/>
        <result type="tiles" name="input">
            <param name="titleKey">global.title.register</param>
            <param name="location">register</param>
        </result>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">index</result>
    </action>

    <action name="goRegister" class="registerAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultWithoutAuthenticationStack"/>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">register</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">index</result>
    </action>
```

And my jsp :

```
    <s:form method="post" action="goRegister" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="usernameRegister" id="usernameRegister" key="global.username" labelposition="left" />
    <s:password name="passwordRegister" id="passwordRegister" key="global.password" labelposition="left" />
    <s:password name="passwordConfirmRegister" id="passwordConfirmRegister" key="global.password.confirm" labelposition="left" />
    <s:textfield name="emailRegister" id="emailRegister" key="global.email" labelposition="left" />
    <s:submit key="global.register" name="submitRegister" method="goRegister"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

I found the answer to messages preservation [here](http://glindholm.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/preserving-messages-across-a-redirect-in-struts-2/), the guy store the differents action messages (messages, errors, fields error) in session when we are in a redirect situation and push them to the action messages otherwise

Here is my implementation (you will find I add success messages to the default messages and errors messages) :

```
public class MessagesInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6230422534075664728L;
private Map<String, Object> session;

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    MyAction action = (MyAction) invocation.getAction();

    this.addSessionMessagesInActionMessages(action);

    String output = invocation.invoke();
    Result result = invocation.getResult();

    // If it's a redirection, store the messages in session
    if(result instanceof ServletRedirectResult || result instanceof ServletActionRedirectResult)
        this.addActionMessagesInSessionMessages(action);

    return output;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void addSessionMessagesInActionMessages(MyAction action) {
    Object messagesObject = getSession().remove(SESSION_ACTION_MESSAGES);
    if (messagesObject != null) {
        List<String> sessionMessages = (List<String>)messagesObject;
        for (String sessionMessage : sessionMessages) {
            action.addActionMessage(sessionMessage);
        }
    }

    Object errorsObject = getSession().remove(SESSION_ACTION_ERRORS);
    if (errorsObject != null) {
        List<String> sessionErrors = (List<String>)errorsObject;
        for (String sessionError : sessionErrors) {
            action.addActionError(sessionError);
        }
    }

    Object successObject = getSession().remove(SESSION_ACTION_SUCCESS);
    if (successObject != null) {
        List<String> sessionSuccessList = (List<String>)successObject;
        for (String sessionSuccess : sessionSuccessList) {
            action.addActionSuccess(sessionSuccess);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map<String, List<String>> fieldErrors = (Map) session.remove(SESSION_FIELD_ERRORS);
    if (fieldErrors != null && fieldErrors.size() > 0){
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> fieldError : fieldErrors.entrySet()){
            for (String message : fieldError.getValue()){
                action.addFieldError(fieldError.getKey(), message);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void addActionMessagesInSessionMessages(MyAction action) throws Exception{
    Collection<String> actionErrors = action.getActionErrors();

    if (actionErrors != null && actionErrors.size() > 0){
       session.put(SESSION_ACTION_ERRORS, actionErrors);
    }

    Collection<String> actionMessages = action.getActionMessages();

    if (actionMessages != null && actionMessages.size() > 0){
       session.put(SESSION_ACTION_MESSAGES, actionMessages);
    }

    Collection<String> actionSuccess = action.getActionSuccess();

    if (actionSuccess != null && actionSuccess.size() > 0){
       session.put(SESSION_ACTION_SUCCESS, actionSuccess);
    }

    Map<String, List<String>> fieldErrors = action.getFieldErrors();

    if (fieldErrors != null && fieldErrors.size() > 0){
       session.put(SESSION_FIELD_ERRORS, fieldErrors);
    }
}

public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;
}
```

}

MyAction inherits ActionSupport

Hope this will help someone ;)

Action mesages and field validation message are now preserved with no refresh problem

But my fields values are now blank, how do I retrieve / store them to repopulate my fields ?

Comment: `defaultWithoutAuthenticationStack` is this your own Interceptor if so what about `MessagesInterceptor`  and where do u use it?

Comment: You're right, It seems I forgot to add some code, the `defaultWithoutAuthenticationStack` is my own implementation, more precicely it's an interceptor stack derived from the defaultStack (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-TheDefaultConfiguration) where I have added my `MessagesInterceptor`